# I ran a 3D gain plot for patch antenna but the result looks truncated. Did I mess up the sweep angles? The theta and phi?

Tags: rf, antenna

[image: image of plot and angles]

I have been stuck on this for long, using HFSS by the way.

Comment: \$\theta\$ usually varies from -90 to 90.

Comment: I made an infinite ground instead of a perfect E, I guess that’s where the error came from

Comment: You can post it as an answer yourself. And possibly give the corrected plot in the answer.

Comment: I made it an infinite ground instead of a perfect E and that affected the radiation in the ground plane.

Comment: Please provide a more comprehensive answer, the system flagged the answer for shortness